# How to restrict a table to be only modified by triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: Foo and FooHistory. All the operation (insert/update/delete) on Foo will be recorded in FooHistory by triggers. How do I configure so that FooHistory table data can't be manually changed otherwise?

Comment: Don't GRANT anything but SELECT.

Comment: @jarlh what is the user role of the trigger code?